# How to extend \PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::createRunner in recent versions of PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

[The current version is defined as this](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/de16033ce97d69c3a13019467ef20251ef06be62/src/TextUI/Command.php#L127-L133):

```php
    /**
     * Create a TestRunner, override in subclasses.
     */
    protected function createRunner(): TestRunner
    {
        return new TestRunner($this->arguments['loader']);
    }
```

What's however not directly visible that `\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner`, the **returned type**, is declared as:

```php
final class TestRunner…
```

Either I got it all wrong, but looks to me in fact you can't really extend the `createRunner` because you'd have to return a `final` class which you can't really extend… ‍♀️

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you have to extend it in the first place?

Comment: @PhilipWeinke Trying to figure out ways for https://github.com/wizaplace/phpunit-slicer , since >= 8.5 the whole approach doesn't work anymore and I'm trying the least obtrusive way to solve this.